# Lazy load pages random error:ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:

Tags: ionic3

I run into the following error every now and then.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:MenuPage
    at d (polyfills.js:3)
    at l (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:322)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:310)
    at nav-controller-base.js:365
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:4125)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at n.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at n.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

I'm not aware of any steps to reproduce and **this error is not causing any problem at all** The app is working normally and the Menu Page is displayed correctly.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
  name: "menu",
  segment: "app"
}
)
@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.html'
})
export class MenuPage {}
```

I had checked my project and the menu page is only used by its `IonicPage` name `"menu"`.

There is already an ionic forum [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-3-lazy-loading-invalid-link-tabspage/88021) but I am already following the proposed accepted solution which is about giving a name to the `IonicPage` annotation.

Answer (score 16):

Same thing happens to me sometimes. Likewise I was not able to determine where the error comes from, as it happens only rarely. Looks like a bug with the app scripts, as stopping and starting "ionic serve" seems to solve the issue.

Comment: This is usually my go-to solution for most of my issues recently. Works 4 out of 5 times

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: I have this many many times a day. The only thing that works is restarting the app.

Answer (score 14):

According to your error, it looks like you are trying to use the class name `MenuPage` as a deep link. `this.navCtrl.push('MenuPage');`

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:MenuPage
```

In your case, you declared the deep link as "menu". So you should use:

```
this.navCtrl.push('menu');
```

Or if you want, keep using the class, but without quotes: `this.navCtrl.push(MenuPage);`

Comment: That was the first thing I thought of. I searched the whole code for the literal `MenuPage` but it is was never used to navigate to the page.

Answer (score 11):

Restart your server and you will be fine.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see you mentioning anything about a `menu.module.ts` file. To configure lazy loading you need a module file per page/component.

This file is required so Ionic can understand which components need to be loaded when your page is initialized. Here's an example of a module file for a page:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';
import { SomeComponentModule } from '../../components/some/some.component.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MenuPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MenuPage),
        HeaderComponentModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MenuPage
    ]
})
export class MenuPageModule { }
```

The component in this file is just an example. So if you have a component called SomeComponent in your project. Then you should import it in your page.module, only if you're using that component in your page of course.

The SomeComponent also has a module file which exports the SomeComponent as SomeComponentModule which can be imported in the page.module file.

Adding `IonicPageModule.forChild(MenuPage)` to the imports is required as well.

Finally, if you created a module file per component/page then you can remove all component/page imports from your `app.module.ts` file.

The rest you've mentioned is configured correctly. The `IonicPage()` annotation is still required per page and you should be able to navigate use `this.navCtrl.push('menu')` since you've set the name to 'menu'.

NOTE: please make sure the filename of your module file has the same name as the name of the page filename but with `.module` appended to it. For example a `menu.ts` page file should have a corresponding `menu.module.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. I already have the module exposing the Page. I did not add it to reduce the question size.

Comment: I see, well I had the same issue but my problem was the filename of the module file that was not set correctly because I created the files manually instead of via CLI. So I'd advice to double check your filenames. Also what is the current version of your Ionic?

Comment: Really useful explanation!! Thanks @SolveSoul !!

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't restart your server after adding your new page(in this case MenuPage) stop and restart ionic serve. Error will be solve.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19063869)

Comment: LOL, worked for me too, but @Danielson is right, that's not the best answer though it may work sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when I was doing something like

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
...
openPage(page:string) {
  this.nav.setRoot(page);
}
```

I ended up tracking it down to the fact the literal being passed in was invalid. 
I wanted no more typos or upper instead of lower case in the names, centralising this stuff.

As a consequence I defined an enum of pages and used that everywhere.

```
export enum Page {
  HOME = <any>'HomePage',
  LOGIN = <any>'LoginPage'
}
```

Then used something like:

```
openPage(Page.LOGIN);
```

I tracked it down via **view-controller.js** in "ionic-angular": "3.6.0"

Answer (score 2):

In **MenuPage.ts :** 
add this over the class MenuPage:

```
@IonicPage(
{
  name: 'tabs-page'
})
```

In **app.components.ts**

```
rootPage: string = 'tabs-page';
```

Please try it!

Comment: De Correcto !! Great !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Solved it by changing the "@ionic/app-scripts" to version "2.1.3" under devDependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
"typescript": "2.4.0" }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and  i can resolve this creating the archive module.ts for mi page in this case was tabs

```
import { TabsPage } from './tabs';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TabsPage
    ],
    imports: [
      IonicPageModule.forChild(TabsPage),
    ],
    exports: [
      TabsPage
    ]
})
export class MenuPageModule { }
```

only in case this was added  the import,declarations and entryComponents in the app.module.ts file  remove that. 
All this process  work fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am studying the Lazy load in Ionic 3 too.
Today I had an issue with it. This video explains how to use it [Ionic 3 - Lazy Loading Modules/Routes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7j-P-ElAqe8)

I do not need to use @IonicPage({name: 'name-of-my-page'}), just follow the steps in the video and work perfectly to me.

Hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lazy loading of components :

Just add `@IonicPage()` decorator above the `@Component` decorator imported from 'ionic-angular' and restart your server after saving your work

Example:

```
....
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
....

@IonicPage()
@Component({
templateUrl : '',
})
export class XYZ{
   ........
}
```

Make sure you do not added the same page in app.module.ts file neither in declarations array nor in imports array.

Answer (score 0):

Another case that can cause the problem is load a `lazy-loaded` page as a `modal`. If you want to use a page as a modal you should not make it lazy-loaded! After that you can use that page as a modal:

```
modalCtrl.create(this.somePage).present();
```