# How to get back to root application in IONIC 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic3

How to get back to root application in IONIC 3.

> main.js:1436 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:
>   TabsPage(…)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; 
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'



@Component({   selector: 'page-registrar',  
               templateUrl: 'registrar.html' 
}) 

 export class RegistrarPage {    
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

   ionViewDidLoad(){}


  openHomePage(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');   
  }

}
```

Comment: It's possible you've got a typo with the name of the page 'TabsPage'. But if you are not lazy loading page with @ IonicPage, then you have to use  class name itself and import it - not a string in set root. I say that because your Registrar page doesn't have an @ IonicPage... See my note here. It may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721208/495157

Answer (score 0):

Try this `this.navCtrl.popToRoot()`

From Ionic Doc. This will navigate back to the root of the stack, no matter how far back that is. [Detail Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: I'm using tabs. With this.navCtrl.popToRoot () I get back to the root page, however I need to reload the root page with the first default tab. How is it possible? Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: then using your setRoot method. make sure your are importing tabsPage in this component. and pass reference of that page.

Comment: are you using lazy load? provide some more detail like tabs page and current page's component and template

Comment: I tried using the setRoot with the tab name, but it does not work.