# Cannot get deep links to work "Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: MainPage"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In my (relatively) fresh Ionic 3 app I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: MainPage
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:322)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:310)
    at nav-controller-base.js:365
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

The app was running fine, when I wanted to enable deep links. As suggested I added `IonicPage` to my page components. I basically ended up enabling lazy loading, as I followed every advice or tutorial I could find about `IonicPage`.

The error does not really give any guidance to the actual problem. So I can just guess, that something is wrong in my `app.ts`:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class App {

  rootPage: string = MenuPageName;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Based on which JS files are loaded, it seems as if lazy loading is working now. Sadly, I can’t get rid of this error. I tried a lot of things from the following links:

- [Ionic Uncaught (in promise): invalid link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969482/ionic-uncaught-in-promise-invalid-link),
- [Lazy load pages random error:ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821742/lazy-load-pages-random-errorerror-error-uncaught-in-promise-invalid-link)
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-lazy-loading-invalid-link-tabspage/88021/20

Nothing helped, so finally I am here to ask you for help. I created [a github repo, to demonstrate the problem](https://github.com/RobYed/ionic-split-pane-example).

It would be great to get some help here :)

Comment: I'd add some of the critical code to the post; linking to a github repo is insufficient

Comment: @Will thanks for your response. I edited my post. But as I am writing, the error does not really provide us with helpful information.